# How to expose read model from shared module

Tags: cqrs

I am working on developing a set of assemblies that encapsulate parts of our domain that will be shared by many applications.  Using the example of an order management system, one such assembly will contain all of the core operations an application can perform to/with an order.  We are applying a simple version of CQS/CQRS so that all operations that change the state of the "system" are represented as public commands, such as CancelOrderCommand, ShipOrderCommand and CreateORderCommand.  The command handlers are internal to the assembly.

**The question I am struggling to answer is how to best expose the read model to consuming code?**

The read model will be used by consuming code to perform queries.  I don't know how all of the ways the read model will be used so the interface needs to be flexible to allow any query.

What complicates it for me is that I not only need to expose my aggregate root but there are also several "lookup" lists of related data that client applications may use.  For example, each order has an associated OrderType which is data-driven (i.e., not an enum) and contains several properties that will drive some of our business rules that control what operations can/cannot be performed, etc.  It is easy inside my module to manage this relationship; however, a client application that allows order creation will most likely need to display the list of possible OrderTypes to the user.  As a result, I need to not only expose the list of Order aggregates but the supporting list of OrderTypes (and other lookup lists) from my read model.

How is this typically done?

I'm not sure what else to explain that will help trigger a solution, so please ask away...

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a CQRS based implementation expose a full dataset for ad-hoc querying so this is an interesting situation!  In a typical CQRS scenario you would expose very specific queries because you may want to raise events when they are called (for caching for example - see [this post](http://www.nootn.com.au/2013/03/command-query-separation-to-better.html) for more details on that).

However since this is your design, let's not worry about "typical" or "correct" CQRS, I guess you just need a solution!  One of the best new mechanisms for exposing data for flexible querying I have seen is the [Open Data Protocol (OData)](http://www.odata.org/).  It will allow consumers to implement their own filtering, sorting and paging over a data source you expose.

Most implementations of this seem to deal with relational data.  If you are dealing with a relational data source then OData might be a nice way to go.  I suspect by your comment of "expose my aggregate root" that you might be using a document database?  If so, there is one example I have seen of OData services on top of MongoDB: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2012/10/11/mongodb-odata-provider-now-supports-arrays-and-nested-collections.aspx.

I hope that helps, OData is definitely worth looking into.  It seems to be growing really quickly and is getting good support on both server and client technology platforms.